# Java Semaphore - permit granted without prior release

Tags: java, concurrency, quartz-scheduler, semaphore, deltaspike

I'm writing this question because we faced an scenario in one of the qa environments where it seems like the semaphore failed. 
We have only one semaphore:

`private Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(1);`

It happened that one thread (Quartz job) was running, holding the lock acquired, and then, another job was triggered and got in the middle of the execution.

Both jobs acquire and then release the lock, so if the first one gets delayed, the latter has to wait for the lock to be released by the first one.

The weird part is that the latter didn't wait, **it just passed through the lock.acquire()**

Scenario it's not complex at all, and the code has been working since the very beginning. We weren't able to recreate it so far, I'm clueless. A glitch maybe?

I'm wondering if someone knows if there is a kind of known incompatibility between Quartz and Java Semaphores, or if Java semaphores could fail under certain scenarios

**EDIT**
One more detail, it's an app built on Deltaspike CDI framework

This is the Singleton for handling the lock:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Lock {

  private Lock() {}

  private static class SingletonHolder {
    public static final Lock INSTANCE = new Lock();
  }

  /**
  * Use this method to get a reference to the singleton instance of
  * {@link Lock}
  * 
  * @return the singleton instance
  */
  public static Lock getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
  }

  /**
  * we allow only one thread at at time
  */
  private Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(1);

 public void getLock() throws InterruptedException {
   lock.acquire();
 }

 public void releaseLock() {   
   lock.release();
 }
}
```

This is the first job:

```
@Scheduled(cronExpression = "{cronExp1}")
public class Job1 implements Job {

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {  

    method1();

  }

  public void method1(){
    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();

    try{
      logger.debug("Thread # " + threadId + "Requesting lock...");
      Lock.getInstance().getLock();
      logger.debug("Thread # " + threadId + "Lock acquired.");  

      //...some logic

    }catch (PersistenceException e) {
      //.. handling exception
    }catch (Exception e) {      
      //.. handling exception
    }finally {
      Lock.getInstance().releaseLock();
      logger.debug("Thread # " + threadId + "Lock released.");
    }
  }
}
```

This is the second job:

```
@Scheduled(cronExpression = "{cronExp2}")
public class Job2 implements Job {

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {

    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    try{       
      logger.debug("Thread # " + threadId + "Requesting lock...");
      Lock.getInstance().getLock();
      logger.debug("Thread # " + threadId + "Lock acquired.");

      //...some logic

    }catch (PersistenceException e) {
      //.. handling exception
    }catch (Exception e) {      
      //.. handling exception
    }finally {
      Lock.getInstance().releaseLock();
      logger.debug("Thread # " + threadId + "Lock released.");
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the only difference between the jobs (other than the logic), is that Job1 enters the critical zone inside method1, while Job2 does in inside the execute method

Comment: Could you share a minimal and verifiable example of how said `lock` is used in your code?

Comment: thanks @MickMnemonic , I just updated the issue with code information

Comment: How do you know that two threads are able to acquire permits at the same time? I notice that your `finally` block does not print a message until _after_ it has already released the permit. So, it is theoretically possible for a second thread to print the "Lock acquired" message after the first thread has released a permit, but before the first thread prints its message.

Comment: Good catch, but I know from the logs of the logic part of each job. I have a lot of log entries from Job2 mixed with log entries from Job1, thing that never happened before. Time gap is 30 mins, first job took 45. At minute 31, more or less, I start seeing mixed logs from both jobs. Beyond that, since both of them interact with the database, I saw inconsistencies in there, due to this overlapping. Hope it helps

Comment: Are these jobs running in the same JVM?

Comment: yes, it's an standalone app, one process, one jvm